# How do you make "0 comments" appear on the bottom, relative to the timestamp's position, *without* editing the HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I tried achieving positioning the Comments span next to the timestamp via Absolute positioning, but that approach was bad because it would end up in a different place depending on the length of the text above.

I can't edit the HTML directly (to my knowledge) due to this being a Wordpress setup, so the only tools I have are CSS and JS editing. Any ideas on how to make it look like [pic below] through CSS/js?

[image]

```html
<div class="entry-body">
  <header class="entry-header">
    <div class="entry-before-title">
      <p class="entry-meta entry-stats g1-meta g1-meta g1-current-background"><span class="entry-views "><strong>30.4k</strong><span> Views</span></span><span class="entry-comments-link entry-comments-link-0"><a href="https://wimm.com/2017/12/10/25-delicious-things-to-cook-in-september/#respond"><strong>0</strong> <span>Comments</span></a>
        </span>
      </p>
      <span class="entry-categories "><span class="entry-categories-inner"><span class="entry-categories-label">in</span> <a href="https://wimm.com/category/bimber-food/" class="entry-category entry-category-item-21">Food</a></span>
      </span>
    </div>
    <h3 class="g1-delta g1-delta-1st entry-title"><a href="https://wimm.com/2017/12/10/25-delicious-things-to-cook-in-september/" rel="bookmark">25 Delicious Things To Cook In September</a></h3>
  </header>
  <div class="entry-summary">
    <p> Consectetur quis, elementum eu arcu. Nunc ornare arcu lacus, quis aliquet odio bibendum non. Nam vitae libero mauris. Suspendisse vitae purus ligula. Morbi sed diam eget dolor posuere convallis vel vel nisl. Nulla sagittis efficitur ex, at sodales
      massa pulvinar a. Nunc quis lacinia eros. Fusce ac ipsum gravida, tristique sed felis augue dictum nec. </p>
  </div>
  <footer>
    <p class="g1-meta entry-meta entry-byline entry-byline-s entry-byline-with-avatar">
      <span class="entry-author">
            <span class="entry-meta-label">by</span>
        <a href="https://wimm.com/author/admin/" title="Posts by admin" rel="author">
        <img data-expand="600" alt='' src='data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,%3Csvg xmlns%3D' http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg ' viewBox%3D'0 0 24 24 '%2F%3E' data-src='https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/9f221658beaba2ee853f978fa48f49c2?s=24&#038;d=mm&#038;r=g'
          data-srcset='https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/9f221658beaba2ee853f978fa48f49c2?s=48&#038;d=mm&#038;r=g 2x' class='lazyload avatar avatar-24 photo' height='24' width='24' />
        <strong>admin</strong>
      </a>
      </span>
      <time class="entry-date" datetime="2017-12-10T11:52:51+00:00">December 10, 2017, 11:52 am</time> </p>
  </footer>
  <div class="entry-todome g1-dropable snax">
    <div class="snax-voting snax-voting-positive snax-voting-xs" data-snax-item-id="297">
      <div class="snax-voting-score">
        <strong>6200</strong> points </div>
        <a href="#" class="snax-voting-upvote snax-vote snax-vote-up snax-guest-voting" title="Upvote" data-snax-item-id="297" data-snax-author-id="0" data-snax-nonce="58b09e0f01"><span class="snax-vote-icon snax-vote-icon-caret"></span>Upvote</a>
        <a href="#" class="snax-voting-downvote snax-vote snax-vote-down snax-guest-voting" title="Downvote" data-snax-item-id="297" data-snax-author-id="0" data-snax-nonce="58b09e0f01">          <span class="snax-vote-icon snax-vote-icon-caret"></span>Downvote
        </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You keep asking the same question by opening up new questions. Stop. Edit your original question. And it's not true you can't edit because it's a WordPress site. As I said in a comment on your original question, you can create a child theme and edit template files directly in your child theme.

Comment: JSFiddle has nothing to do with this, I removed it from the title and question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the element and reposition it after the `p.entry-byline` section, or as the bottom of the entire entry if you want.

First you detach it from its parent then you can append it to the desired target.

```js
[...document.querySelectorAll('.entry-body')].forEach(entryBody => {
  moveElement(
    entryBody.querySelector('p.entry-stats span.entry-comments-link a'),
    entryBody.querySelector('p.entry-byline')
  );
});

/**
 * Moves an element by detaching it from its parent and appending it to
 * a target.
 * @param {HTMLElement|String} ref - Element to detach and move
 * @param {HTMLElement|String} target - Element where ref will be appended
 * @return Returns the element that was moved
 */
function moveElement(ref, target) {
  if (typeof target === 'string') target = document.querySelector(target);
  target.appendChild(detatchElement(ref));
  return ref;
}

/**
 * Detaches an element from its parent.
 * @param {HTMLElement|String} ref - Element to detach from its parent
 * @return Returns the detached element
 */
function detatchElement(ref) {
  if (typeof ref === 'string') ref = document.querySelector(ref);
  return ref.parentElement.removeChild(ref);
}
```

```html
<div class="entry-body">
  <header class="entry-header">
    <div class="entry-before-title">
      <p class="entry-meta entry-stats g1-meta g1-meta g1-current-background">
        <span class="entry-views ">
          <strong>30.4k</strong>
          <span> Views</span>
        </span>
        <span class="entry-comments-link entry-comments-link-0">
          <a href="https://example.com/2017/12/10/25-delicious-things-to-cook-in-september/#respond">
            <strong>0</strong>
            <span>Comments</span>
          </a>
        </span>
      </p>
      <span class="entry-categories "><span class="entry-categories-inner"><span class="entry-categories-label">in</span> <a href="https://example.com/category/bimber-food/" class="entry-category entry-category-item-21">Food</a></span>
      </span>
    </div>
    <h3 class="g1-delta g1-delta-1st entry-title"><a href="https://example.com/2017/12/10/25-delicious-things-to-cook-in-september/" rel="bookmark">25 Delicious Things To Cook In September</a></h3>
  </header>
  <div class="entry-summary">
    <p> Consectetur quis, elementum eu arcu. Nunc ornare arcu lacus, quis aliquet odio bibendum non. Nam vitae libero mauris. Suspendisse vitae purus ligula. Morbi sed diam eget dolor posuere convallis vel vel nisl. Nulla sagittis efficitur ex, at sodales
      massa pulvinar a. Nunc quis lacinia eros. Fusce ac ipsum gravida, tristique sed felis augue dictum nec. </p>
  </div>
  <footer>
    <p class="g1-meta entry-meta entry-byline entry-byline-s entry-byline-with-avatar">
      <span class="entry-author">
            <span class="entry-meta-label">by</span>
        <a href="https://example.com/author/admin/" title="Posts by admin" rel="author">
        <img data-expand="600" alt='' src='data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,%3Csvg xmlns%3D' http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg ' viewBox%3D'0 0 24 24 '%2F%3E' data-src='https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/9f221658beaba2ee853f978fa48f49c2?s=24&#038;d=mm&#038;r=g'
          data-srcset='https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/9f221658beaba2ee853f978fa48f49c2?s=48&#038;d=mm&#038;r=g 2x' class='lazyload avatar avatar-24 photo' height='24' width='24' />
        <strong>admin</strong>
      </a>
      </span>
      <time class="entry-date" datetime="2017-12-10T11:52:51+00:00">December 10, 2017, 11:52 am</time> </p>
  </footer>
  <div class="entry-todome g1-dropable snax">
    <div class="snax-voting snax-voting-positive snax-voting-xs" data-snax-item-id="297">
      <div class="snax-voting-score">
        <strong>6200</strong> points
      </div>
      <a href="#" class="snax-voting-upvote snax-vote snax-vote-up snax-guest-voting" title="Upvote" data-snax-item-id="297" data-snax-author-id="0" data-snax-nonce="58b09e0f01"><span class="snax-vote-icon snax-vote-icon-caret"></span>Upvote</a>
      <a href="#" class="snax-voting-downvote snax-vote snax-vote-down snax-guest-voting" title="Downvote" data-snax-item-id="297" data-snax-author-id="0" data-snax-nonce="58b09e0f01">          <span class="snax-vote-icon snax-vote-icon-caret"></span>Downvote
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @m0a you cannot run your own JavaScript script after the page loads?

Comment: @m0a Just make sure you place it in a spot that runs after the content is rendered to the DOM. Maybe call it in the `DOMContentLoaded` event?

Comment: Sorry but I'm still struggling. This is what I'm getting, whether I try to put it in DOMContentLoaded event or not: `syntax error, unexpected '...' (T_ELLIPSIS), expecting ']'` It's a function.php. I don't know if it's a PHP problem or Wordpress.

Comment: @m0a You can’t run client-side JS in PHP, make sure the script is running only in the browser. If it’s complaining about the ellipsis then you are using an older browser or you are trying to run it in PHP.

Answer (score 1):

https://codepen.io/pen/?editors=1100
how about using position: absolute from the bottom? is the bottom content dynamic too?

```
.entry-comments-link entry-comments-link-0 {
position: absolute;
  bottom: 53px;
  left: 270px;
}

.entry-body {
  position: relative;
}enter code here`
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used WordPress before so I'm not sure where you can enter JS but provided there is only the one `<time>` tag you could use the following:

```
var elem = document.createElement('a');
var linkText = document.createTextNode("\t 0 Comments");
elem.appendChild(linkText);
elem.title = "Comments";
elem.href = "http://yourlinkhere.com";
var timeElem = document.getElementsByTagName("time")[0];
timeElem.parentNode.insertBefore(elem, timeElem.nextSibling);
```