# modify / move an existing html tag in the DOM (javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, getelementbyid, children, getelementsbyclassname

I want to move my div class="contentlinks" tag with its content, to place it in the div class="row" after the div class="col-12".
Here is the basic html architecture :

```
<span id="data">
     <section id="" class="thesectionQ">
         <div class="container">
             <div class="row">
                 <div class="col-12">
                     <h1>Title</h1>
                 </div>
            </div>
         </div>
     </section>
     <div class="col-12 contentlinks">
         <a class="btn">link1</a><a class="btn">link2</a>
     </div>
 </span>
```

Tags are dynamically created in js... my problem is that I can't seem to use appendChild ...

my problem is that I can't seem to use appendChild ...

I'm trying to target my section with a class="thesectionQ" in a variable as well as my div class="contentlinks" that I want to move :

for example...

```
   var thedata2 = document.getElementById('data').getElementsByClassName('thesectionQ'); 
   var thedata = document.getElementById('data').getElementsByClassName('contentlinks');
   thedata2.appendChild(thedata);
```

but I have errors ... and too often

Comment: Maybe you could adapt this move function I wrote?: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62903478/1762224

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you make "0 comments" appear on the bottom, relative to the timestamp's position, \*without\* editing the HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62903242/how-do-you-make-0-comments-appear-on-the-bottom-relative-to-the-timestamps-p)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

give section id so it become easy.

```
document.querySelector('#sectionId div.row')
.appendChild(document.querySelector('div.contentlinks'))
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply ! It's easier like that... but unfortunately I have an error... "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous>"

Comment: Did you add id to the section ? it worked for me with that, make the section with id="sectionId"

Comment: I added id=sectionId" to the section then integrated your code ... I think the error comes from the fact that the section tag and its content as well as the div with the class="contentlinks" are generated in javascript ... and so I do not manage to target them well ...

Comment: you should add the elemnts in the dom befor editing

Comment: indeed, I had a problem in the order of the calls ... Thank you very much, it works now!